# What happens to dark elixir?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Say you don't have a dark elixir storage, then you raid somebody who does and gain 500 dark elixir. What happens to that dark elixir? Is it unobtainable? Just gone?

Thanks

Comment: A lot of same questions asked already...

Answer (score 1):

The dark elixir simply will just be gone.